# Separate notification for individual sites on SE sites

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, notifications, user-experience

I would like to ask, would it fit the design on SE sites to have each site notify its user separately?

This is what I mean, suppose I am a participant of  **Movies.SE**, **Stack Overflow** etc etc, and I log on to StackOverflow, if I have a notification pop up, it should be notifications that relate only to StackOverflow not any other sites and when I later go on **Movies.SE** I should get notifications for Movies.SE only... maybe with the only exception of their respective meta sites.

The reason I am asking is sometimes we come here with different agendas, like when you get referred by Google to a programming question, or maybe you want to come here and answer questions of certain nature, in order not deviate of your agenda by following these notifications to other sites with different topics I think this is good; because sometimes since that is not the reason I came here even though I see the notifications I ignore them, and when you later come back more notifications slaps you hence you can't keep up with others and it might look you actually ignored them or the question asked or you failed to accept an answer etc etc.

For example, I came here to seek an answer from StackOverflow and I saw a notification, from Movies.SE and I clicked on it. A lot has happened then, I ended up posting a question on its meta site, now I am 45 minutes in, and I have ditched the search for a solution and finding myself amazed by some answers on Movies & TV & now I can't leave.

So suppose that was added as a feature I think it will not only help me a lot, but others too, and also help me stay focused, you see.

It rarely happens, I know, but when it happens its very bad. Now I am an hour in...

Comment: Why is it SE's job to keep you on task? If you have stuff you need to do, ignore the other notifications until you have time.

Comment: hmm, okay i will, wow! i have met you an both meta sites Madam catija :) . but to your question - so i stay in harmony with it(SE sites) and keep coming back? :) nevermind@Catija

Comment: Don't say sir or madam, you may get the gender wrong...

Comment: @PythonMaster He [already did](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2154/do-deleted-questions-affect-reputation#comment7655_2154)...

Comment: @Catija  am not a He lmao.. joking :)

Comment: guessing you are not a Sir? @PythonMaster well its part of my language - and i like showing respect to people here because alot older than i am. you can always correct me if i am wrong. :)

Comment: I am a sir but it is kinda weird though...

Answer (score 5):

I think that is a bad idea. Notifications are there for a reason: they require your action or at least attention.

I don't want to wait for days before I visit that site I don't spend too much time on to see then I have missed a notification for an answer to my question for days.

If you are active on more than one site, it is very useful to have cross-site notifications. My personal experience: I really like them.

If you don't have the time to take the appropriate action at the time you see it, just write it down for a later moment, or check your older notifications more often.

Comment: Thanks for your answer too Sir, but if you spend less time on a site means your interest level for it is down, so till it appreciates you can care less or, nevermind sir thank you, i appreciate it.

Comment: Agreed, but what if I ask a question on Seasoned Advice, not my most active site. While I am on SO, I had like to see if an answer comes in.

Answer (score 4):

No.

With people active in multiple sites, especially moderators and Community Managers, they will struggle by having to visit every single site to see if something new happened over and over. This will waste a lot of time and is undesirable.

Our current notifications system is just fine, allowing us to see what is happening to all of our accounts wherever you are, which is what we all like and hope to keep for the future. So to simply *downgrade* the system and force us to visit each site like every five minutes, this would be useless and time-consuming.

Anyways, notifications are there so they can alert us about something new and take action if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sir. now i can look at it from both sides. i really appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the other answers that this would be a bad idea for those of us who are actually active across multiple sites, but I'm adding an answer to suggest a workaround for you.

If you want to focus on, say, SO and ignore everything else, then ignore that red notification entirely.  Instead, go to your user profile.  On the "Activity" tab (what you'll see by default for your own profile), look at the "responses" tab.  If there's a number there, you have stuff waiting.  Everything there will be only from your current site.  Click on it to see the details:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: wow! Thank you madam Monica, guess SE sites are now perfect- you just have to find its usage. to speak of your solution, i did it before reading this -(ignoring the red button) and it took me two days to reply :), well Thank you. :)

Comment: SE has many imperfections; take a look at all the upvoted feature requests to see that. :-)  Sometimes things are there but you just have to find them, though.  Another helpful tip: try mousing over things in the UI; there are lots of tooltips that you might never think to look for.