# Any way to remove notifications from one SE site while using another site?

Tags: support, notifications, top-bar

Is it possible to stop comments and reputation notifications from a particular SE site from appearing in your SE mailbox / reputation icons on the bar area while using other SE sites?

[image: what I'm calling the menu bar area]

This is **not** a feature request, just a question.

The context is that I heavily use certain sites for my job and side businesses, but I've also signed up for other sites. In the past I've found it productive to keep my top SE site open on one monitor while working, so that I can see updates as they occur.

Unfortunately, I didn't exercise sufficient domain expertise when I tried using other, mostly recreational SE sites recently. Now I get lots of unimportant notifications from the recreational sites even when I'm on the professional sites.

If deleting my profile on the recreational SE sites is possible, necessary and sufficient, then that's an acceptable solution. If there's a less drastic solution, then that would be preferable.

I don't want to stop all notifications, I just want to get away from the constant notifications from some recreational sites, so that I can use my main sites more productively again.

Comment: Any particular reason for the down votes?

Comment: Down votes on Meta mean that people disagree with this suggestion or idea.

Comment: @ThomasOwens It's **not** a suggestion or idea. It's a question. There's nothing to disagree with. I'll try to make that more clear with an edit.

Comment: The first edit had a title of "Remove notifications from one SE site". The wording makes it seem like you are looking for a feature to be added. People don't agree that this needs to be a feature or that this is a concern, so they are down voting the question. It's how Meta works.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Oh ok, that makes sense. Yea I should've phrased the title better.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that this question (though as a FR) has been asked before...

Comment: @Catija got a link?

Comment: Ah, found it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274531/separate-notification-for-individual-sites-on-se-sites

Comment: @Catija Thanks, fair enough. I asked because I thought I might see something useful in there, but unfortunately I do not. I guess at this point my question boils down to "is there a way to delete my accounts from the recreational sites?"

Comment: It's for this very reason that I use two different profiles/accounts/addresses to separate my hobbies from more "serious" sites.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is kind of the opposite of the functionality that is desired by most. Especially for those who use multiple sites, it is an incredibly useful way to track notifications.

I think your only course of action will be to disassociate yourself from those sites whose notification annoys you.

Or alternatively, it should be very easy to see from a simple click which sites the notifications are from, without having to visit the site. It's surely not the end of the world to read a small notifier box.

And eventually, if you have no activity on those sites, the notifications will die away - old posts typically end up with minimal or no activity on them after a while.

In addition to technical fixes, please read this [question](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/q/94/54) over on Personal Productivity Stack Exchange which discussed distractions from things like notifications.

Comment: Or alternatively, only check it half hourly, or hourly. We cover off some of the pros and cons of checking notifications over on Personal Productivity Stack Exchange.

Comment: "I don't think anyone would not want to have an option." [Too many options make them all harder to find](http://ometer.com/preferences.html). But perhaps the real problem is the work-life split: checking notifications for sites you use at work should not cause notifications for sites you use in time off work to be considered read.

Comment: @Hack-R For "not being a feature request" your comments certainly make it look like this is a FR...

Comment: @Catija I was replying to a statement make in the answer